# I need a clean url without the parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Hello i need to make my url clean and i just do not know were to start as it is mind boggling, i have read numerous things in regards to clean urls but i have no idea.

This what i am getting on woorank as i am doing my seo.

Warning! We've detected parameters in a significant number of URLs.

I am unsure if this is right i have taken my real domain out and put my site instead

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^//(\.)?My site/.*$[NC]
#RewriteRule .(png|gif|jpg)$ – [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ My site.co.uk$  [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*)  My site.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thank you J C

Comment: Hello and thank you for getting back to me, what examples do i have to give? so sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

A basic htaccess can look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite.co.uk [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1 [L]
```

For every new parameters you just add ([^/.]+)/ and extra parameter in the end..

What happens in code is up to you, but you will need a standard way of working if you want to use something like this.. .

**NOTE:** you can't just implement this now, because your site needs to be fully build to the structure of your htaccess.. So if you would replace this now, alot of others things might get broken soon... .

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.

Comment: No problem, I hope this helped you, or gave you a better insight in your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. As Naruto pointed out. We need to know the structure of your code. Give some examples of how the urls are now and what you want them to look like. The examples will explain a bit how you might have programmed the website.

e.g. different php file for each page /about.php, /register.php or a single entry /index.php with every page having the same parameter keys.

- /index.php?page=page1&foo=bar&qux=norf
- /index.php?page=page2&foo=bar

or perhaps each page has different parameter names

- /index.php?page=page1&foo=bar
- /index.php?page=page2&qux=norf

What you can always do is redirect to a single index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

index.php now needs to route everything approperiately. This basically does the same as what Naruto suggests but instead in php directly and this might be easier for you.
How this routing happens depends on your code and is up to you. But let us assume that you have a different file for each page with different parameters. You could do this without changing the rest of your code.

```
// FROM: /shop.php?category=software&subcategory=webdevelopment
// TO:   /shop/software/webdevelopment
$path = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($path[0] == 'shop') { 
   $_GET['category'] == $path[1];
   $_GET['subcategory'] == $path[2]; 
   include('shop.php'); 
}
```

This way only one file needs to be edited and the rest of your code can still work with the $_GET. This is the same as what you would do in your htaccess.

Comment: Thank you for your help i will digest the answers i have been given from all of you. Thank you again. Jennifer Clarke.